# Android dumpstate analysis

Tags: android, logging, dump, crash-dumps

I was trying to debug an issue in my application .Only possibility of the issue is my thread might have hanged somewhere(but its should be waiting)..When took a close look to duumpstate log I noted following log

Cmd line: com.test.myapp

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
.
.
.

```
"pool-2-thread-1" prio=10 tid=20 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x426986e0 self=0x5ae85520
  | sysTid=3211 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1520669672
  | state=S schedstat=( 9170292 19258957 35 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4268ed88> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=20 (pool-2-thread-1)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1231)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:323)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1052)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:780)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
```

Above lines point to my suspected thread.
What does DALVIK THREADS mean in dump state log? Is that the threads which are alive currently or thread which are alive + which have been alive?
What does state=S schedstat=( 9170292 19258957 35 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 mean?Is it suspended state?
 waiting on <0x4268ed88> (a java.lang.VMThread) --> whats does this mean ? Is it waiting and alive?

Comment: Are you using a Nexus 7 running Android 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logs, the only reason I can think of that could have triggered an ANR is:

As far as i know, usually in Java every thread is associated with 2 components. One being Program counter and the other being Garbage Collector. So every thread will have a gc monitor happening throughout.

**- waiting on <0x4268ed88> (a java.lang.VMThread)** held by tid=20 (poo

VMThreads are ideally used to handle this aspect of monitoring gc, almost parallelly. So what i could think of, for your scenario, is your app's some component is trying to acquire a lock but is unable to because VMThread is holding the lock, unreleased yet (may be due to some major GC op), thus waiting for vmthread to release the lock.

You might want to check your main log dump which has gc activities logged, that might give you a better picture as to why gc was hogging this threads CPU time so much and then app profiling may help. Jus check.